# my code is doing half of what i want it to do. help please

Tags: java

The code is supposed to reverse a string so if i input " hi how are you " it should return " you are how hi " and the words come out in the right order but they come out with the words reversed too (e.g "ouy era woh ih") does anyone see what i should add or take out ?

```
import java.util.*;
public class ReverseString
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String original, reverse = "";
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a string to reverse");
        original = in.nextLine();

        int length = original.length();

        for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
            reverse =reverse + original.charAt(i);

            System.out.println("Reverse of entered string is "+reverse);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Reverse does exactly same. If you want words in reverse, may be split the string and print from last element to first element.

Comment: You don't even separate the words (ie tokenize). How is it suppose to do what you want ?

Comment: This question is all about "let's get StackOverflow do my homework".

Answer (score 0):

You need to break the string into words like this:

```
splitArray = original.split("\\s+");
```

Or with more details:

```
public class ReverseString {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String original, reverse = "";
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a string to reverse");
        original = in.nextLine();

        String[] splitArray;
        try {
            splitArray = original.split("\\s+");
            for (int i = splitArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                reverse = reverse + splitArray[i] + " ";
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Reverse of entered string is: " + reverse);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
run:
Enter a string to reverse
this is a test
Reverse of entered string is: test a is this
```

Comment: @JoelGaytan If it worked accept and upvote the answer so that others don't continue answering

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to split and access the array in reversed order:

```
String str = "hi how are you";

String[] words = str.split(" ");

StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

     if(i != ( words.length - 1)) buffer.append(" ");

     buffer.append(words[i]);

     System.out.println(words[i]);
}
```

Comment: That's going to put each word on it's own line, isn't it?

Comment: You can store the words in a buffer as per my updated code

Answer (score 0):

This reversed word order inside `str`:

```
String [] parts = str.split (" ");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();
for (int i = parts.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (sb.length () > 0) sb.append (' ');
    sb.append (parts [i]);
}
str = sb.toString ();
```